# Deleting an entity record in a many to many relationship with EF6

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am doing something wrong when trying to remove a related record.
I have a Customer model and a CustomerGroup model. A customer can belong to multiple customergroups.

I want to be able to add and remove a customer from a customergroup. Adding is the easy part, when I try to remove a customer from a customergroup the entire record is deleted from the customergroup table

To make things easy to understand here is my code.

```
 [Table("CustomerGroups")]
public class CustomerGroupModel
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerGroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

     [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual List<Customer> CustomersInGroup { get; set; }
}
```

My Customer model

```
   [Table("Customers")]
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{

    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }


    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Groups")]
    //change this as ICollection failed with restsharp to bindICollection<CustomerGroupModel> SelectedGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomerGroupModel> SelectedGroups { get; set; }


}
```

My FluentApi

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SelectedGroups)
            .WithMany(x => x.CustomersInGroup).Map(
                m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
                    m.MapRightKey("CustomerGroupId");
                    m.ToTable("CustomersInGroups");
                });
```

As you can see I generate a table called CustomersInGroups.

When I try to update customer groups I want to delete all existing records then reinsert the newly selected ones (unless there is a better way of doing this)

```
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var contextCustomer = context.Customers
                    .Include("SelectedGroups")
                    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id==customer.Customer.Id); 

                contextCustomer.SelectedGroups.ToList()
                        .ForEach(r => context.CustomerGroups.Remove(r));
                context.SaveChanges();

             }
```

When I execute this all records from the table CustomerGroups are deleted. How do I only delete the related records from the customersingroups table?

Any advice would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the CustomerGroup records are deleted is that you remove them from the context that is translated as removing them entirely from the database. To remove only the relationships between the CustomerGroup instances related to the selected customer you have to assign an empty list to the SelectedGroups property:

```
contextCustomer.SelectedGroups = new List<CustomerGroups>();
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Odd having to new up a new list before saving the context. It does work just weird :)

Comment: @DiverDan It's really not if you think about it; by assigning a new list to this property, you're discarding the old list **but not the entities it contains**.  Alternatively, I'm pretty sure you can remove the entities from the list (**not from the `DbSet`**), perhaps even by using [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axy4fbh.aspx).